# connect to two databases in dhis.conf

Tags: dhis-2

I need to deploy a second instance of DHIS2 on my server. I already have the first one running very well.

The challenge I have is that DHIS2 only uses one configuration file with the code below. I am confused how to setup a connection to my second database.

Please advise.

```
connection.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
connection.driver_class = org.postgresql.Driver
connection.url = jdbc:postgresql:millenium
connection.username = dhis
connection.password = dhis
connection.schema = update
encryption.password = abcd
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run your instances with separate environment variables to point to two different DHIS2_HOME paths. Each path can contain it's own dhis2.conf, with it's own database.

For example, if you are using Tomcat to host your instances, you can set the "setenv.sh" file to set up the DHIS2_HOME variable.